# Simple form give checkboxes a class

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

This is my code

```
<%= simple_form_for [current_employee, @preference] do |f|%>
  <%= f.association :jobterms,   as: :check_boxes, label: false%>
<% end %>
```

It generates this HTML

```
<span class="checkbox">
  <label for="preference_jobterm_ids_1">
    <input class="check_boxes optional" type="checkbox" value="1" name="preference[jobterm_ids][]" id="preference_jobterm_ids_1">
    "Employee"
  </label>
</span>
```

Is it possible to give the "Employee" generated text a surrounding class?

I'm trying to make the checkbox look like a button and thus accessing the text with the label will also affect my styling of my border.

[image]